# NodeJS Wait for function in for loop to finish before continuing

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I basically have this for loop which runs a function that opens a puppeteer window and goes to a link, however, I want this to be done sequentially as right now all the puppeteer windows open at the same time.

Here is the loop:

```
for(var i=0; i < 3; i++){
  if (i != 0){
    enter();
  }
}
```

And here is my function **enter**:

```
async function enter(){

   browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
   page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto(url);

}
```

Right now if I were to run that code 2 puppeteer windows would open however I would like 1 to open, go to the link, and then have the next one open and go to the link, and so on...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you familiar with asynchronous functionality (promises, async/await, callbacks, etc) in general?  If you are using nodejs for anything more than `hello world`, I strongly suggest you find some quick tutorials as this will continue to affect you

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting your `enter` call and that is reason it is not waiting. You need to await it.

```
for(var i=0; i < 3; i++){
  if (i != 0){
    await enter();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your loop into an async function and `await` every `enter()` call:

```
async function openWindows() {
  for(var i=0; i < 3; i++){
    if (i != 0){
      await enter();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my loop is a bit more complicated than that I just simplified it as an example and I'm unable to throw the whole loop in an async function because then when I call await enter(); it throws the error: "await is only valid in async function"